# Finding Goodput in ns2

Tags: ns2

I am trying to find Goodput in a dumbell shaped topology in ns2 so as to compare goodput values for TCP Reno, NewReno,Tahoe. Can anybody please help? I am able to create topology, to run the Protocols and obtain .nam file. But how to analyse it to find goodput is the problem. Goodput is original data transmitted per unit time. But how can I remove headers, etc from the packets to get effective amount of data (also ignoring the retransmission) sent per unit time?

Comment: Where are you stuck? The topology? Setting the TCP types? Producing the trace file? Analyzing it to calculate the goodput? It is impossible to answer this question as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

```
   hdr_size = pkt_size % $x
   # where $x is the packet's data part size

   pkt_size -= hdr_size
   # Store received packet's size
   recvdSize += pkt_size
```

then use formula 
       (recvdSize/(stopTime-startTime))*(8/1000)

to find the good put..